# Visual Studio error MSB3491: The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process, dissapears after the next build

Tags: visual-studio, qt, compiler-errors

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2019. When I build the solution I get the error:

```
Error: MSB3491  Could not write lines to file

The process cannot access the file '..bin\objects\core\Release\x64\core.tlog\core.write.1u.tlog' 
because it is being used by another process. FILE: ..\QtMsBuild\qt_globals.targets  line: 407
```

which leads me to line 407:

```
<WriteLinesToFile Condition="'@(clean_log)' != ''"
  File="$(TLogLocation)$(ProjectName).write.1u.tlog"
  Lines="^%(clean_log.Source);@(clean_log->'%(Fullpath)')"
  Encoding="Unicode"/>
```

this error disapears after I run the build again, which is the strange part. I found some similar problem MSB3491 here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/890376/custom-build-step-leads-to-error-msb3491-could-not.html. But this solution did not work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in QT, they already released fix but I did not tried it yet. Here is the Qt bug tracer report: https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt-labs/vstools/+/332804.